# Talend open studio Error with Mssql

Tags: java, etl, talend

Im using talend open studio to ETL in Mssql , But im getting the following Error

```
Exception in component tMSSqlInput_1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.talend.designer.components.util.mssql.MSSqlGenerateTimestampUtil.getDate(MSSqlGenerateTimestampUtil.java:68)
    at test.dw_0_1.dw.tMSSqlInput_1Process(dw.java:8501)
    at test.dw_0_1.dw.runJobInTOS(dw.java:10759)
    at test.dw_0_1.dw.main(dw.java:10633)
```

But im not mapping any **"timestamp"** filed

What went wrong and how can i solve this

Can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a few tips that may solve your problem.

1. Check if you connection is working properly
2. Identify which column is causing the problem
3. Look out for any Date field and make sure it is checked is as nullable
4. You may need to set a date format in the Date pattern (press control + space in the Date Patter column)
   [image]

Comment: How can i do this step 2. Identify which column is causing the problem

Comment: Tune up the query a bit, if you are familiar with SQL, replace the "*" for the column names until you track down with is the conflicting one or use the Talend SQLBuilder. Good luck

Comment: Okay , Im actually not mapping the Date Time Column , My Table has the column but Im getting only the columns whos data type is String